# Blocking specific users from using Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs, blocking, microsoft-edge

How can I block specific ("standard") users from using Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 Pro? NTFS permissions on:

```
C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe
```

don't seem to work normally:  the permissions seem to be read-only.

Comment: You want to block IE or Edge?  Your question is confusing  Just uninstall IE the method used on previous versions of Windows still works.  It currently isn't possible to disable Edge.  Why isn't just setting a different default browser an option?

Comment: I'm not sure why my question was confusing or deserving of a down-vote. I wrote I that I'd like to block Edge and _"I'd also like to block Internet Explorer"_   In any case, I've successfully disabled IE using "Turn on/off Windows Features" per your suggestion (thank you!). Accordingly, I've edited my question to only deal with Edge, not IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that doing the first 9 steps listed [**here**](http://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-remove-microsoft-edge-from-windows-10-491534.shtml) did the trick. After taking ownership, I used regular NTFS permissions to deny permissions on the users I'm trying to block from using Edge.

Comment: I've since come across Edge Blocker - discussed [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/edge-blocker-block-edge-browser) and available for download here:  
http://www.sordum.org/9312/edge-blocker-v1-0/